# Attempting to merge three columns in CSV, updating original CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

#### Some example data:

```
title1|title2|title3|title4|merge
test|data|here|and
test|data|343|AND
",3|data|343|and
```

#### My attempt at coding this:

```
import csv
import StringIO

storedoutput = StringIO.StringIO()
fields = ('title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4', 'merge')
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as input_csv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_csv, fields, delimiter='|')
    for counter, row in enumerate(reader):
        counter += 1
        #print row
        if counter != 1:
            for field in fields:
                if field == "merge":
                    row['merge'] = ("%s%s%s" % (row["title1"], row["title3"], row["title4"]))
                    print row
                    storedoutput.writelines(','.join(map(str, row)) + '\n')

contents = storedoutput.getvalue()
storedoutput.close()

print "".join(contents)

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as input_csv:
    input_csv = input_csv.read().strip()

output_csv = []
output_csv.append(contents.strip())

if "".join(output_csv) != input_csv:
    with open('file.csv', 'wb') as new_csv:
        new_csv.write("".join(output_csv))
```

#### Output should be

```
title1|title2|title3|title4|merge
test|data|here|and|testhereand
test|data|343|AND|test343AND
",3|data|343|and|",3343and
```

For your reference upon running this code the first print it prints the rows as I would hope then to appear in the output csv. However the second print prints the title row x times where x is the number of rows.

Any input or corrections or working code would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a CSV file when the delimiter is a pipe?  The use of a solo double quote in a field in line 4 of your test data is likely to confuse just about any CSV processing code. Are you sure you want this program to overwrite the original file? What output do you get from your code?

Comment: Obviously its not strictly speaking a csv, but what should I have refered to it as?The output of printing `row`, works correctly, however printing `join(contents)` yeilds the title row for the number of rows there are in the data.Thanks GTPE

Comment: Arguably, the 'correct' term is [DSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values), reserving CSV for comma-separated values and TSV for tab-separated values.  There's another argument that says I'm an old fogey for thinking CSV is inappropriate. I suspect fewer people would recognize DSV than would recognize CSV, so it isn't all that unreasonable. It is not a dreadfully serious criticism, which is also why it's couched as a question.

Comment: I hope I can continue to get away with using csv for such data, since I agree DSV would get less of an audience!

Comment: I I don't understand the last line; what's going on with the quoting?

Comment: The last line of the output or my attempt to code this?

Comment: The output.  Am I to take it that you're not using `"` as an escape character?

Comment: indeed, that is part of one of the elements `",3` hence forming `",3343and` as a final merged element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import StringIO

stored_output = StringIO.StringIO()

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as input_csv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_csv, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(stored_output, reader.fieldnames, delimiter="|",quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar=None)

    merge_cols = "title1", "title3", "title4"

    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        row["merge"] = ''.join(row[col] for col in merge_cols)
        writer.writerow(row)

    contents = stored_output.getvalue()
    stored_output.close()
    print contents

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as input_csv:
    input_csv = input_csv.read().strip()

if input_csv != contents.strip():
    with open('file.csv', 'wb') as new_csv:
        new_csv.write("".join(contents))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we can make this a **lot** simpler.  Dealing with the rogue `"` was a bit of a nuisance, I admit, because you have to work hard to tell Python you don't want to worry about it.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as input_csv, open("new_file.csv", "wb") as output_csv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_csv, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_csv, reader.fieldnames, delimiter="|",quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar=None)

    merge_cols = "title1", "title3", "title4"

    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        row["merge"] = ''.join(row[col] for col in merge_cols)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

produces

```
$ cat new_file.csv 
title1|title2|title3|title4|merge
test|data|here|and|testhereand
test|data|343|AND|test343AND
",3|data|343|and|",3343and
```

Note that even though you wanted the original file updated, I refused.  Why?  It's a bad idea, because then you can destroy your data while working on it.

How can I be so sure?  Because that's exactly what I did when I first ran your code, and I know better. ;^)

Comment: Ok thanks with regards to overwriting data files, I will bear that in mind for all future data manipulations.

Comment: Due to the nature of the files and their size It would actually be preferable to me to be able to write them back to the same file, they are stored in dropbox, so i can easily revert to an older version if I accidentally destroy data. I know in general this is bad practice, but there is a fail safe in place.

Comment: quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE did the trick. @DSM Thanks for that - from the docs ..."the programmer can also specify individual formatting parameters, which have the same names as the attributes defined below for the Dialect class" .  I totally missed that.

Answer (score 2):

That double quote in the last line is definitely messing up the csv.DictReader().
This works:

```
new_lines = []
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    # skip the first line
    new_lines.append(f.next().strip())
    for line in f:
        # the newline and split the fields
        line = line.strip().split('|')
        # exctract the field data you want
        title1, title3, title4 = line[0], line[2], line[3]
        # turn the field data into a string and append in to the rest
        line.append(''.join([title1, title3, title4]))
        # save the new line for later
        new_lines.append('|'.join(line))

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    # make one long string and write it to the new file
    f.write('\n'.join(new_lines))
```

Comment: Due to the nature of the files and their size It would actually be preferable to me to be able to write them back to the same file, they are stored in dropbox, so i can easily revert to an older version if I accidentally destroy data. I know in general this is bad practice, but there is a fail safe in place.